# CSS restrict height of subsequent columns based off the height of the first column

Tags: css

I am about to use some JavaScript to do this, but perhaps there is another way.
I have a container, row and two columns. What I want, is the content in column 1 to dictact the height of column 2, even if column 2 has items that go past (preferably, I want it to go onto a new line).
Here is the html:

```
<v-container class="pl-0 pr-0" fluid>
  <v-row class="ml-0 mr-0">
    <v-col cols="2" class="pl-0 pr-0">
      <v-list color="blue-010">
         <!-- omitted for brevity -->
      </v-list>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="10" class="section-blue-002">
         <!-- omitted for brevity -->
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</v-container>
```

And this is what it looks like.

[image]

I would like it if the content on the right, did not exceed the height of the highlighted content on the left.
Is this possible with CSS?